# How to get .NET HttpContext for isolated code block

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

In .NET is it possible to get the HttpContext of the current page from within an external class?

So, for example in my page test1.aspx codebehind I've got:

```
    Dim blah As New FeedWriter()
    blah.Run()
```

But inside FeedWriter.vb, can I get the HttpContext of test1.aspx? Or would I have to pass it in to Run()? (I'm unwilling to do the latter because FeedWriter implements an interface which will need to be re-written if it's to take arguments)

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Why do you need the HttpContext, which property do you need? Request, Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Current` property of the `HttpContext` class:

```
HttpContext.Current;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't get HttpContext as an object - it's telling me that System.Web.HttpContenxt is not declared even though I've added System.Web as a project reference.

Comment: You need to be running under asp.net ie IIS or using Cassini in the dev environment.